# Error adding dependency to project

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to add a library as a dependency but it keeps giving me this error:

> Class android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat.AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl
>   has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
>
> Execution failed for task ':BrooklynTech:dexDebug'.
>   Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':BrooklynTech:dexDebug'

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
}
    dependencies {
        compile files('libs/Simple-Rss2-Android.jar')
        compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
        compile 'uk.co.androidalliance:edgeeffectoverride:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
        compile project(':libraries:calendar-card')
        compile 'com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.0.0' }
```

the dependency I added was for jazzylistview - https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than one of your dependencies is including the classes from the v4 support library; you'll need to track it down. You ought to be able to open up the jar files from the project viewer and find the culprit.

Ideally none of your dependencies ought to be bundling the support library; it's the responsibility of your app's build to make sure that gets finally linked in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but could you try the following snippet. Maybe the transitive libs are causing the trouble

```
dependencies{
    ...
    compile ('com.twotoasters.jazzylistview:library:1.0.0'){
        transitive = false   
    }
}
```

cheers,
René